# Meteor package constraints Error

Tags: meteor, packaging, meteor-accounts

I am trying to fork a Meteor package locally.

So I downloaded it from github to */meteorprj/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled*. When I try to add it via *meteor add accounts-ui-unstyled* I am getting the following error message:

`While selecting package versions:
error: conflict: constraints on accounts-ui-unstyled cannot be satisfied.
Constraints come from:
<top level>`

What does this error message mean?
Where does the error lie?
In the *package.js* file there is no version constraint whatsoever and all the packages that *api.use* uses are present in the versions file.

Should be easy to answer I just haven't found anything regarding that error.

Comment: package name should be username:package, remove it first if you have it installed from atmosphere

Comment: It's a bug/issue with how meteor selects package version. See the full discussion [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4170)

Comment: Hi, I ended up just adding the package as plain js.